# adding an ActionListener to my button makes the GUI invisible

Tags: java

```
private void addButton() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    button = new JButton("Convert");
    button.addActionListener( new ButtonListener());

    buttonPanel.add(button);
    contents.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

when the line `button.addActionListener( new ButtonListener());` is commented out, my program GUI shows up just fine. But uncommented, my program is invisible.

here's part of my ButtonListener class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double total = 0.0;
        double leftNum = Double.parseDouble(leftText.getText());
        String leftSelection = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();


        if(leftSelection.equals("Shim")) {
            total = leftNum * kShim;
        }


        //String rightSelection = (String) rightBox.getSelectedItem();


        rightText.setText(total + " ");
        }
```

So far I have 3 classes: my main class, gui class, and buttonlistener class. I'm trying to make a currency converter that converts between USD and currencies form the fantasy series "The Kingkiller Chronicle"

The main class simply initializes a new instance of the gui class. I had all my exchange rates and dollar values in the main class but the buttonlistener class didn't have access to those variables so I moved them

The addButton method is inside my gui class along with a few other things.

Comment: Does `button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());` throw any exception?

Comment: Nope, no exceptions thrown. The program runs but the GUI is invisible. There's only one warning in the main class: `This method has a constructor name` referring to  `public static void main(String[] args) {`

Comment: How do you know it doesn't throw an exception? (I've seen lots of people who write `try { ...rest of their code here... } catch(Exception e) {}` and then go "Nope, no exception!")